# AJAX call to invoke a remote JS function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a slideshow (jQuery Cycle2 plugin) running on a server. The slideshow can be paused and stopped with buttons invoking jQuery functions on the slideshow.

The application is structured as follows: In the index.php I define the slideshow functions (stop, pause, etc.) and an AJAX call within a function that sends a POST to another PHP script to load the slideshow content from the server. So far, this works nicely.

Now, I want to have another script (or maybe Webservice) remoteControl.php that allows me to remote control my slideshow from a third device. So say I run the slideshow on the server and from another site (probably same domain) I call the slideshow functions in the index.php using also AJAX.
At the moment this does not work. 
In the body section of my index.php I put:

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    $actionOnSlideshow = $_POST['action'];
    echo '<script>'.$actionOnSlideshow.'();</script>';
}
?>
```

followed by all the other content and scripts for the slideshow.
The `$actionOnSlideshow` variable contains the respective function sent from the AJAX request in the remoteControl.php.
Could this relate to the same-origin-policy. The second AJAX call however is from the same domain so this should not be the issue!?

Comment: You would have to have a way to push out the change to the device doing the display. You may want to consider having the display device poll the server to see if any updates were made by the remote.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I thought AJAX would do that but of course it doesn't if I don't specify anything in the done/success function. Do you have any suggestions how I could achieve this here. I don't have to load any HTML, just invoke the JS functions again.

Comment: You could always call the AJAX in a timing loop.

Comment: With setTimeout(function, ms)? To check whether the DOM has changed meanwhile or to tell the DOM that it should check for changes?

Comment: Either setTimeout or setInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm assuming you don't want to rebuild your app using something like
   [meteor js](https://www.meteor.com/) on the server, which pushes updates to the client. 
   You'd have to rebuild your php pages so I'm just mentioning that
   for reference.
2. [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is promising but not yet stable enough
   cross-platform for production.
3. If you are running nginx and can recompile, you can use the [NGiNX_HTTP_Push_Module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/) combined with [AJAX Long Polling](http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2010/08/27/comet-with-nginx-and-jquery/).
4. And finally if all else fails, AJAX using good old [setTimeout and setInterval](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) will work.